# Selected value in form_dropdown not appearing after submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using form_dropdown to create a dropdown box.  It works properly in that all of the values are listed properly and the desired category filtering is achieved when I submit a selected option.  However on the resulting view the dropdown says "Filter by Category", whereas I want it to show the $selected_category, which is a string.

Here's the code:

```
echo form_dropdown('company_category_ids', array(0 => ' Filter by Category ') + $unique_category_ids, $selected_category, ' id="category"');?>
```

Thank you for any help or advice!

Edit - adding content of the variables:

`$unique_category_ids:`

```
    Array( [58] => Coffee/Tea Accessories [179] => Food Storage [247] => Outdoor Trash)
```

$selected category can be any of these three items (Coffee/Tea Accessories, Food Storage, or Outdoor Trash).

Comment: Can you post an example of the content/structure of arrays `$unique_category_ids` and `$selected_category` ?

Comment: @Jeemusu just posted, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jeemeesu Thanks for your comment. I should have posted more complete information initially.  `$selected_category` is a text string, which is defined by a `$selected_category_id`.

```
$selected_category=$unique_category_ids[$selected_category_id];
```

where `$selected_category_id` is either 58, 179, or 247.  The problem is that I was using `$selected_category` (which was either Coffee/Tea Accessories, Food Storage, or Outdoor Trash) instead of `$selected_category_id`.

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be a problem in the array. I think it should be...

```
$unique_category_ids = array("value_1" => "Filter by Size", "value_2" => "Filter by Color");
$selected_category = "value_2"; //just for example
echo form_dropdown('company_category_ids', array("value_3" => ' Filter by Category ') + $unique_category_ids, $selected_category, ' id="category"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well from my experience with CI, it seems that the problem is in the format. This is what you have:

```
echo form_dropdown(
            'company_category_ids',  <----GOOD (this is the name of the Select tag)
            array(0 => ' Filter by Category '), <----WRONG this array should be your options
            $unique_category_ids, <---GOOD options
            $selected_category, <--GOOD
            'id="category"'); <---Good
```

The problem seems to be that you have too many parameters. This should take 4 parameters at the most. Your code should be like this:

```
$unique_category_ids = array(0 => ' Filter by Category ');
$selected_category = '0';
echo form_dropdown(
            'company_category_ids',
            $unique_category_ids, 
            $selected_category,
            'id="category"');
```

Comment: If you look closely you will see that there is a plus between `array(0 => ' Filter by Category ')` and `$unique_category_ids` . This is one parameter and the plus operator is combining the two arrays.

Comment: PHP comments are either `// this is a comment` || `/* This is a comment */` || `# this is a comment`